Packet loss between Host B and Router, but no packet loss between Host B and Host A or Host A and Router
I'm troubleshooting a packet loss issue with my IT department and am all out of ideas. I currently have the layer 2 folks blaming the layer 3 folks and vice versa - I'm just the guy caught in the middle whose application isn't functioning correctly. Here's my scenario and am curious if anything jumps out:
I recently added Host B to a VLAN'd subnet. This device is experiencing 80% packet loss when pinging the Router. I assumed it was maybe a bad cable, however, Host B is able to ping existing Host A very very reliably. So I then assumed maybe the router is malfunctioning, however, Host A to Router are able to ping very very reliably. Thus the issue seems to be very specific between the Router and the new Host B.
Host B is a Windows 10 based device. I've triple checked IPv4 settings and that the gateway address is correct. However, the problem persists where I'm experiencing 80% packet loss while trying to ping the Router. Additionally, the router experiences 80% packet loss when pinging Host B.
Like I said, I initially wanted to blame bad Host B cable/hardware, however, if that was the case it should not be able to ping Host A as reliably as it is. I've checked NIC settings on Host B. MTU size looks fine, link status looks happy, however, you can see the discarded receive packets increment when running a netstat -e
Anything jump out? Sound like a layer 2 or layer 3 issue? Note - I don't have great visibility into specific switch settings and VLANs. All I know is that everything appears to be VLAN'd correctly.
Symptoms Continued:

On occasion when Host B is able to ping Router, there is an ARP entry made. However, when the pings start to fail I notice the ARP entry has disappeared. Is there a reason why the ARP entry would go missing occasionally?


Did you check to see if one of them has a duplex mismatch?

Unfortunately, questions about network you do not directly control are off-topic here, as are host configurations. It sounds like Host B is either hard set with a speed/duplex and the switch is not, or vice versa. That would cause a duplex mismatch that does the type of thing you describe.

While we're bordering the allowed scope of this board (getting host specific, networks not under your direct control), there like 4 things to keep in mind:

Ping doesn't tell you the communication direction which lost packets. It might've been the Echo request packet that was lost, it might've been the Echo packet. Resort to a tool that can generate unidirectional data flows and report results from both sending and receiving end.
Frame Errors (like CRC/checksum, over/undersize and similar) can happen in one direction, but not the other. Any network segment or link along the path can be affected unidirectionally. Work with your network team to find out the real path your packets are taking between host B and router. Also be sure to check with them if any of the switches along the path are of cut-through [1] or store-and-forward [2] nature.
Depending on the given network topology, the path to over there might be different from the path back here. Request packets might take a different path through switches and inter switch links than the response packets do. This applies to both packets being routed as well as packets being switched. Add this to the (possibly) unidirectional nature of packet loss (see above), and you'll see where this is heading.
Routers, even more so L3-switches with their workload split between ASICs (forwarding muscle) and CPUs (brains), have more important things to do than to respond to ICMP Echo requests (which are usually handled by the CPU in L3-Switches), and they rate-limit the amount of packets to reach the CPU. Your pings might be triggering a threshold of that Router or L3-switch.
off by one errors.   ( Sorry, could not resist... ;-) )

Oh, and while you're seeing an increment of RX discards in your host side netstat -e output, that's where I'd start to look. Something's happening on that last stretch of cable from switch to host, in that direction, and it causes host B to discard incoming frames or packets.
[1] A cut-through switch will start forwarding an ethernet frame downstream (... possibly to a host), while still ingesting the rest of the ethernet frame (... possibly from an upstream switch). If the incoming frame eventually turns out to be corrupt (bad checksum), it will "stomp" (zeroize) the CRC trailer of the already egressing ethernet frame - and the downstream device will - obviously - detect an RX checksum error.
[2] A store-and-forward switch will ingest the incoming ethernet frame, buffer and checksum it and if so needed discard it and bump the RX error counter on the ingress port. Downstream devices will experience packet loss, but not RX checksum errors.

seeing an increment of RX discards in your host side ... that's where I'd start to look - yes, exactly there. Run a packet capture if needed to find out what kind of frames are dropped.
